# Проблема роутинга в asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Здравствуйте есть такая проблема с которой не могу разобраться

```
<div class="btn-group " role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary"
                               asp-controller="Trainers"
                               asp-route-id="@trainer.Trainer.Id" asp-action="Update">
                                <img class="" asp-append-version="true" src="~/img/icons8-edit-40.png" alt="photo" />
                            </a>
                            <form asp-controller="Trainers" asp-action="Delete" class="margin-for-actions">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@trainer.Trainer.Id" />
                                <input type="image" src ="~/img/icons8-trash-can-40.png" class="btn btn-danger" value="DeleteTrainer">
                            </form>

                        </div>
```

есть такая html разметка на удаление и апдейт, на update идет get запрос
и все нормальн о

```
<form style="width: 40%" asp-action="Update">
    <input asp-for="TrainerId"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TrainerGroupId"></label><br/>
        <span asp-validation-for="TrainerGroupId" class="text-danger"></span>
        <select class="form-control" asp-for="TrainerGroupId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Groups, "Id", "Name"))">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Info"></label><br/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Info" class="text-danger"></span>
        <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="Info"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"
           class="btn btn-primary"
           value="Update"/>
    <a asp-action="TableTrainers"
       class="btn btn-dark">
        Return to list
    </a>
</form>
```

а есть форма редактирования
после того как жму кнопку update то такое ощущение что вызывается post запрос на удаление
вот сам контроллер

```
 [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Update([FromForm] TrainerUpdateModel trainerFromView)
        {
            var trainerForUpdate = _unitOfWork.TrainerRepository.Find(trainerFromView.TrainerId);

            if (trainerForUpdate == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(new TrainerUpdateModel(trainerForUpdate, _unitOfWork.TrainerGroupRepository.List()));
            }



            trainerForUpdate.TrainerGroupId = trainerFromView.TrainerGroupId;
            trainerForUpdate.Info = trainerFromView.Info;
            _unitOfWork.Commit();

            return RedirectToAction("TableTrainers");


        }

        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Delete([FromForm] Guid id)
        {
            var trainer = _unitOfWork.TrainerRepository.Find(id);
            if (trainer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _unitOfWork.TrainerRepository.Remove(trainer);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();


            return RedirectToAction("TableTrainers");

        }




        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Update([FromQuery] Guid id)
        {
            var specification = new Specification<Trainer>(x=>x.Id==id,"User");
            var trainer = _unitOfWork.TrainerRepository.Find(specification);
            if (trainer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _unitOfWork.TrainerRepository.Remove(trainer);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();

         
          
            return View(new TrainerUpdateModel(trainer, _unitOfWork.TrainerGroupRepository.List()));

        }
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: По коду должен вызыватся метод Update , включите отладчик и посмотрите что происходит

Comment: дебажил, заходит в нужный метод, но в итоге такой сущности в бд нету, и в итоге выдает notFound(), как будто вызывается на удаление метод

Comment: если not found , тогда смотритрите на дебаге какие значения вы ишите есть ли они базе, правельный регистр букв может вы пишете большими а там маленькие буквы. посмотрите какой ид он верный или нет, вобшем выполните эту операцию в ручном режиме.

Answer (score 0):

Все решил, извините за тупость

```
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Update([FromQuery] Guid id)
        {
            var specification = new Specification<Trainer>(x=>x.Id==id,"User");
            var trainer = _unitOfWork.TrainerRepository.Find(specification);
            if (trainer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


//Удаляю здесь тренера по глупости 
            _unitOfWork.TrainerRepository.Remove(trainer);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();

         
          
            return View(new TrainerUpdateModel(trainer, _unitOfWork.TrainerGroupRepository.List()));

        }
```